# Induction cooker

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering, heat-conduction

I was using an induction cooker and I kept my steel utensil empty on it and switched it on. After some time the bottom part of it became red hot but the upper part of it was completely cool. Why does this happen? The temperature difference was the same even after some time. Why is the conductive property of the metal not working?

Comment: What upper part?

Comment: @BobD the upper part of the utensil

Comment: You mean like a fork, knife or spoon?

Comment: @BobD No the upper part of the same utensil(pan) which is made up of thin steel

Comment: So it’s the upper part of the induction  cooker? And how far up is it from the bottom? If you could post a picture it would help